# REG EXPORT single value to .reg file

Tags: powershell, command-line, registry, backup

I want to export a single registry value to a file using PowerShell (eventually scripting to backup a bunch of registry values).

I can view the file with QUERY:

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" /v LimitBlankPasswordUse
>>
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
    LimitBlankPasswordUse    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

However, I can't export the single value.

`REQ EXPORT` has no `/v` flag, so:

```
REG EXPORT "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" \v "LimitBlankPasswordUse" LBPU.reg
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
```

Doesn't work.

If I try to export the value I get:

```
REG EXPORT "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LimitBlankPasswordUse" LBPU.reg
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

And if I simply do the folder:

```
REG EXPORT "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\" Lsa.reg
The operation completed successfully.
```

I get a .reg file which includes the correct value:key pair `"LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000001` - but also all the others. Which is no use. I want one pair, not hundreds.

How do I export a single value to a .reg file?

Comment: The answer is no. However, if you are willing to use PowerShell, there are other ways to accomplish something similar to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no *direct* way of achieving what you want**, and **given that you want a `.reg` file as output, using PowerShell's cmdlets (such as [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item), [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty), and [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue)) is *not* an option** - unless you're prepared to *emulate* the `.reg` file format *in all aspects*, which is nontrivial both in terms of effort and complexity.<sup>[1]</sup>

The best approach in your case is to **first export the *whole key*, with `reg.exe export`, to a *temporary* file**, and **then extract and export only the header lines and the data-value pair of interest**.

Given that a single data-value pair can *span multiple lines*, this isn't straightforward, but the following should work robustly (you could wrap it in a *function* for convenience and reuse):

```
# Determine the key path and the name of the value to export...
$keyPath = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa'
$valueName = 'LimitBlankPasswordUse'
# ... and the output file path.
$outFile = 'LBPU.reg'

# Create a temporary file and export the whole key to it.
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
$null = reg.exe export $keyPath $tempFile /y

# Extract the header lines and the key's *immediate* value children.
# Note: reg.exe export invariably exports *recursively*, so that any 
#       descendant keys are exported as well, which we want to exclude.
$null = (Get-Content -Raw $tempFile) -match '(?s)^(.+?\])\r\n(.+?)\r\n(?:\r\n|\z)'
Remove-Item $tempFile

# Extract the header lines (format identifier and key path)...
$headerLinesBlock = $Matches[1]
# ... and the key's immediate children as value-data pairs
$valueLinesBlock = $Matches[2]

# Extract the specific value-data pair of interest.
# Note: Such a pair can span *multiple* lines, if "\" is used as the
#       line-continuation character at the end of a line, as is common
#       with hex. data.
#       Continuation lines always start with a *space*, so a data-value pair
#       ends either with a new line whose first char. is a non-whitespace char. 
#       or with the end of the input string.
if ($valueLinesBlock -notmatch "(?sm)^`"$valueName`"=.+?(?=(\r\n\S|\z))") {
  throw "Value name not found: $valueName"
}
$valueDataPair = $Matches[0]

# Save the header lines and the data-value pair line(s) to the result file.
# Note that .reg files are "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files.
$headerLinesBlock, $valueDataPair | Set-Content -Encoding Unicode $outFile
```

`$outFile` receives the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
"LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000001
```

---

<sup>[1] To name a few challenges: `REG_DWORD` and `REG_QWORD` values must be represented as *hex* values, `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values, when queried with `Get-ItemProperty` are invariably *expanded*, so you wouldn't preserve the actual value as stored in the registry; furthermore, `REG_EXPAND_SZ`  and `REG_MULTI_SZ` values must be represented as types `hex(2)` and `hex(7)` in the form of hex *byte arrays*, respectively.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You haven't used PowerShell at all here.  As zett42 said, this is a `Get-ItemProperty` problem.  If you *must* have a `.reg` file as the output then you could easily create one providing you have simple case such as this where the output is a single `dword`.  The approach will struggle if you have numerous items and more complex datatypes.

```
$lsa = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" -Name LimitBlankPasswordUse
$path = $lsa.PSPath.Split('::')
Set-Content foo.reg "Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`r`n`r`n[$($path[2])]`r`n`"LimitBlankPasswordUse`"=dword:$($lsa.LimitBlankPasswordUse)"
```

You can hard code or script as much as you need depending upon your overall objective.  Probably export to CSV and then apply then at the target with `Set-ItemProperty`.

Comment: As an aside: To get a registry value's _data_ directly, use `Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa LimitBlankPasswordUse` ([`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) is PSv5+)